# EasyAutocomplete não encontra o valor pesquisado no campo

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Estou fazendo um sistema de pedidos e preciso que o campo onde o vendedor seleciona o cliente tenha a opção de pesquisa.
Tentei com o datalist do html mas a pesquisa não funcionou muito bem, então estou tentando utilizar o easyautocomplete, tenho um json com aproximadamente 700 clientes salvo no localStorage, a estrutura do json é como está no exemplo, porem alterei os dados por questões de privacidade, enfim, a questão é que independente do que eu pesquise no campo, o resultado mostrado nas options é sempre o mesmo, se eu pesquisar por "josé" por exemplo, que seria o último registro do json, o item "José da silva" não é listado, aparecem sempre os 6 primeiros itens do JSON, o que pode ser o problema?

```
<script>
var options = {
    data: [{"idCliente":"2305","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE 01","nrCnpjCpf":"123.456.789-12","dsBairro":"SAO CRISTOVAO","nrTelefone":"54 9999999999","dsEndereco":"RUA CASTRO ALVES","nrCelular":"54 9999999999","dsCidade":"Cidade ABC"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 01","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 02","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 03","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 04","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 06","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"ações","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"José da silva","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"}],
    getValue: function(element) {
      return element.razaosocial;
    }
};
$("#cliente").easyAutocomplete(options);
</script>
<input id="cliente" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Não coloque link com códigos na pergunta, coloque o código para poder ser analisado!

Comment: Ok, não sei mexer muito bem no stackoverflow ainda, vou editar a pargunta, obrigado pela dica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom, segundo a [documentação](http://easyautocomplete.com/guide#sec-data-json) faltou vc passar a propriedade **list** que possui outra propriedade chamada **match** e marcar a propriedade `enable` como sendo **`true`**:

```js
var options = {
  data: [{"idCliente":"2305","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE 01","nrCnpjCpf":"123.456.789-12","dsBairro":"SAO CRISTOVAO","nrTelefone":"54 9999999999","dsEndereco":"RUA CASTRO ALVES","nrCelular":"54 9999999999","dsCidade":"Cidade ABC"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 01","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 02","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 03","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 04","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"CLIENTE TESTE ACENTUAÇÃO 06","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"ações","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"},{"idCliente":"3585","nmFantasia":"","razaosocial":"José da silva","nrCnpjCpf":"987.654.321-00","dsBairro":"INTERIOR","nrTelefone":"","dsEndereco":"CAPELA SANTA LUZIA","nrCelular":"","dsCidade":"Cidade XYZ"}],
  getValue: "razaosocial",
  list: {
    match: {
      enabled: true
    }
  }
};

$("#cliente").easyAutocomplete(options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/jquery.easy-autocomplete.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/easy-autocomplete/1.3.5/easy-autocomplete.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input id="cliente" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Perfeito, funcionou, tinha testado com vários exemplos da documentação, acabei não vendo esse, falha minha, muito obrigado